# How is the fractional binary notation used in the QFT?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-fourier-transform

I am studying the Quantum Fourier Transform and my question regards section 4 from this [link](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform.html). Specifically, I do not understand the step where they rewrite in fractional binary notation- could someone explain to me what that means? I tried to look it up but did not find anything relevant to this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A positive integer $y$ has a binary representation $y_{n-1}\ldots y_{0}$ where $y_k \in \{0,1\}$. For example, for $n=3$, the number $5$ in binary is $\color{red}{101}$. If we do a binary expansion of $5$, we get
$$5 = 2^2*\color{red}1 + 2^1 *\color{red}0 + 2^0 * \color{red}1.$$
In general, we have
$$
\tag{1} y = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k y_k.
$$

Similarly, $\frac{y}{2^n}$ is an integer $y$ divided by $2^n$, so it is a fraction, which also has a binary expansion in terms of fractions $2^{-k}$:
$$\tag{2} \frac{y}{2^n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{-k}y_k.$$

You can derive (2) from (1) by dividing (1) by $2^n$.